# VB.NET Change Form Coordinates to Form Position on Screen

Tags: vb.net

Could anyone tell me if it is possible to set a forms coordinates differently than what the screen coordinates are? I have a form where I need the upper left corner to always be at (zero x) and (zero y) no matter where I move the form on the screen.   I have tried both "PointToScreen and PointToClient"

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove

    Dim ptB As Point
    ptB = Me.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
    Me.Text = ptB.ToString

End Sub
```

Comment: Short answer, NO.  Why would you need this?...and how would it be used?

Comment: As already asked, Why?  Control.PointToClient() and Control.PointToScreen() are normally used to get relative locations

Comment: Is that not how it works already? When I set the location of a Button, I declare it relative to the top left of the form, not the top left of the screen

Comment: Thanks all for the response... I will try my best to explain. I have a form that contains a diagram for users to click on points in the diagram. Those points that were clicked and recorded will later become points/coordinates used in an Excel chart.  In order for it to work properly, I need the upper left of the form to be the zero point. But its actually getting the coordinates of the screen. I will update my post with the code I am using.

Comment: So the users are clicking on a diagram.  Is that diagram displayed directly by the Form?...or is it in a child control such as a PictureBox, Panel, or something else?

Comment: Thanks Idle_Mind... right now the diagram is only in the form background.